# How can I use a SOAP API in my Rails app in Heroku and EngineYard?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, soap, heroku

I've got a pure, working, Rails application hosted on Heroku and another on EngineYard.

I now need it to start communicating with another application. This application exposes that exposes a SOAP interface. How can I connect to the API in my rails app?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible to use SOAP in Rails.